# Call a function from a link in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm creating a table with a delete field in every row.
The delete fields are links. Now I'm wondering; how can I call a function (to delete the data from the database) when you click the link.

the code for the the table:

```
        $header = array("booking day" , "where" , "nr of people", "cancel");
        $rows = null;
        foreach ($res as $booking) {              
            if(isset($venues[$booking->nid]->title)){
                $rows[] = array(
                date("d-m-Y", 
                $booking->date), 
                $venues[$booking->nid]->title, 
                $booking->num_guests,
                l('delete', "LINK HERE" ),
                );
            }
        }
```

I've found an example online that dictates me to do make a new menu page like this:

```
$items['node/%node/delete_slot'] = array(
'title' => 'Delete slot',
'page callback' => 'bookings_delete_booking',
'page arguments' => array(2),
'access arguments' => array('access content'), // whatever see above
'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
```

);

And a new function like this:

```
function bookings_delete_booking($identifier_for_what_percent_is) {
dsm('test');
```

}

When I click the link it goes to a 404 page.

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work?

-Thanks

Comment: What is an example link you're generating?

Comment: If you mean what example I followed. This one: http://drupal.org/node/427866

Comment: I mean http://www.yoursite.com/node/123/delete_slot

Comment: To make sure the menu and function part of the code works, don't worry about the link yet, but just go to the URL directly: yoursite.com/node/123/delete_slot without clicking on your generated link.  Make sure that page pops up before working on the rest of the code.  If it doesn't work, clear your cache!  New menu items are not picked up right away!!  Also, your argument should be array(1).  The first path component (node) is array(0), so you need array(1) to pick up the node id.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

How is the table being generated? Could you not generate it via a view as this has node[delete] option already included?

You will need to flush the cache (page registry) as it will not pick your code up.

Also you want the page arguments line to be the following

```
'page arguments' => array(1)
```

as your argument is positioned second in the URL